# Unable to prove a statement regarding circles and trigonometry.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, circles

I was asked,

A circle has diameter AB also dividing the circle in two separate parts and centre O. A point C on the circumference divides the semicircle into two sector AOC and BOC, BOC being the smallest has angle X. AOC has a chord AC. It is given that the area cut off by AC is twice the area of BOC. Consequently I have to prove 3X = π - sinX.

What I did,

Area of sector AOC,

1/2r^2(π-X).

Area of triangle AOC,

1/2r^2sinX.

Area cut off by chord,

1/2r^2X - 1/2r^2sinX.

Given that the area cut off by chord is twice the area of BOC,

(π-X) - sin(π-X) = 2X.

π - sin(π-X)    = 3X.

This is not equal to the statement also, I don not have to use trig identities.

Comment: *"the area cut off by $AC$"* - does this refer to the area of $\triangle AOC$ or to the area of the region delimited by the circle and the chord $AC$?

Comment: The difference between the areas of sector AOC and triangle AOC.

Comment: I still need help......

Comment: Note that $\sin (\pi - X) = \sin X$.

Comment: How exactly does this work is there no identity involved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area of the sector $BOC$ is $\frac 1 2 r^2 x$.

The area of the sector $AOC$ is $\frac 1 2 r^2 (\pi - x)$.

The area of $\triangle AOC$ is $\frac 1 2 r^2 \sin (\pi - x) = \frac 1 2 r^2 \sin x$.

We are given that $2 \text{ area (sector } BOC) = \text{ area (sector } AOC) - \text{ area }\triangle BOC$, therefore that $2 \cdot \frac 1 2 r^2 x = \frac 1 2 r^2 (\pi - x) - \frac 1 2 r^2 \sin x$ whence, after simplifying by $\frac 1 2 r^2$ and regrouping of the terms with $x$, we get $3x = \pi - \sin x$.